# Unable to access media file belonging to nobody:nobody

Tags: python, django, centos

When I deploy my django project to centos, I am unable to access it through the URL.

The media files uploaded from django admin belong to the user and group `nobody:nobody`.

When I change the ownership to my user, then it is accessible. How to allow these files to be accessed without specifying `chmod` explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACL rights **Access Control List**. 
With this method, you may define the default owners and permissions for the content that will be created in a folder.

On CentOS, you may install it with the following command:

```
yum install acl
```

Once installed, the command **getfacl** will return the acl setup for a specific file:

`getfacl /path/to/your/folder`

The command **setfacl** will set up the access. 
To setup default permissions:

```
setfacl -Rm d:u:username:rwx,g:groupname:rwx /path/to/your/folder
```

The content created in this folder will inherit the default ACL.

Comment: Still no luck @Kevin Lemaire

Comment: Can you provide the return of `ls -la` of the files owned by nobody?

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -la` that will show you owner of file. Run this command in order to reach from outside.

```
chown admin
```

Comment: I need to explicitly specify this after adding media. I want to get this done by default.